# MySQL HAVING MIN() does not return minimum value

Tags: mysql

I'm running stuck on a MySQL query that doesn't do what I want. From a list of product images, I need to get the one with the lowest `order` number. I'm using the query below to do so:

```
SELECT id FROM media
WHERE media.productgroup_id = 102
AND media.product_id= 902
AND media.type = 0
HAVING MIN(media.order)
```

Database table `media` contains:

```
id    | productgroup_id | product_id | order | type
47215 | 102             | 902        | 2     | 0
47216 | 102             | 902        | 1     | 0
47217 | 102             | 902        | 3     | 0
```

Running the query above returns me id `47215`, where I was expecting `47216`. So it returns the minimum id, not the minimum order.

What mistake do I make?

Comment: Your query makes no sense as you're using group function without grouping there

Comment: You are missing a `group by` and a condition to compare the result of `MIN(media.order)` to something (e.g. `having MIN(media.order) = 10`). Every other DBMS would simply reject your query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL is the PHP of the RDBMS's, allowing you to do weird stuff :-)

Comment: MySQL is a strange bird that it allows nonsensical SQL through and actually gives results like that. Unfortunately your SQL statement should just throw an error as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order by the `order` and take the first element

```
SELECT id 
FROM media
WHERE media.productgroup_id = 102
AND media.product_id= 902
AND media.type = 0
order by media.order asc
limit 1
```

`having` is used for groups which you did not build.

Comment: I would say, this is what I need! How simple can it be!

Answer (score 2):

If your criteria were more complex than just min, you could use a subquery to solve this as well. That being said, @jeurgen-d's answer is probably a faster one for your situation. I just want to point out there is more than one way to skin this cat.

```
SELECT id 
FROM media
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT min(id) 
        FROM media 
        WHERE 
            media.productgroup_id = 102
            AND media.product_id= 902
            AND media.type = 0
    ) as m2 
    ON media.id = m2.id
```